# Changing specific column values to factors or levels for sklearn modeling

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am cleaning the credit card data for risk modeling.

I tried to change the credit card column with levels in python, but it didn't work. The data can be downloaded from the following link. [Data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataspelunking/MLwR/master/Machine%20Learning%20with%20R%20(2nd%20Ed.)/Chapter%2005/credit.csv)

I want to change the values of `checking_balance`, `saving_balance` and `employment duration` to levels of 0, 1, 2,3 ... etc.

The following code shows my trial for the `saving_balance` column.

```
credit['savings_balance'].unique()
credit["saving_balance"] = credit["saving_balance"].map(
                           {"unknown":0,"< 100 DM": 1,
                            "< 100 DM": 2, "100 - 500 DM":3,
                            "500 -1000 DM": 4,"> 1000 DM": 5"})
```

The following error message popped-up.

```
File "<ipython-input-19-b70881164cf7>", line 3
credit["saving_balance"] = credit["saving_balance"].map(...)

^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: `credit["saving_balance"] = credit["saving_balance"].map({"unknown":0,"< 100 DM": 1,"< 100 DM": 2, "100 - 500 DM":3,"500 -1000 DM": 4,"> 1000 DM": 5})` remove " at the end after 5

Answer (score 1):

Incase your looking to use sklearn for the same. Have a look at the [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

**Code**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data = np.array(["unknown", "unknown", "< 100 DM"])

# Label Encoder
label = LabelEncoder()
label.fit_transform(data)

# Output
array([1, 1, 0])
```

```
# Inverse transform
label.inverse_transform(np.array([0, 0, 1]))

# Output
array(['< 100 DM', '< 100 DM', 'unknown'], dtype='<U8')
```